# Event on child div

Tags: jquery-selectors

I'd like to make only hovered rectangle switch class – not both.

EDIT:
Updated jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/JE8v6/1/

Comment: can you please explain more what did u needed this jsFiddle to do ?

Comment: Now I realised that I pasted wrong jsfiddle link! I'll replace it in a minute. Done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of work i finally managed to solve your solution
Here is the result
http://jsfiddle.net/JE8v6/4/